# Even Odd rows for only one column in tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working with tables to display data on a webpage.

Right now I've got even odd for `<tr>` to have the rows alternating colors. However, I am going to be freezing the 1st column of the table and having the remaining columns scroll to the left and right.

At the moment, the columns that are scrolling to the left are being seen under the frozen column. If I apply a background color to the cells in the frozen column, the columns that are no longer to be displayed when scrolled to the left are then truly hidden.

I'm calling the first column's cells by using td:nth-child(1).

The problem is that I am using alternating row colors so assigning a background color to td:nth-child(1) makes all cells in that 1st row the same color.

Is it possible to add (odd) and (even) to the nth-child call?

I'd like to use a better method (if there is one) than just assigning classes to each of the cells in the first column.

(NOTE: Added my code 02/12/2018)

```css
table.sidebyside {
 width: 800px;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 }
table.sidebyside th:nth-child(1), table.sidebyside td:nth-child(1) {
 width: 300px !important;
 position:absolute;
 }
table.sidebyside th:nth-child(2), table.sidebyside td:nth-child(2) {
 padding-left: 300px !important;
 }
table.sidebyside th {
 background-color: #4b91ea;
 height: 63px;
 } 
table.sidebyside td:nth-child(1) (odd) {
 background-color: #fff;
 }
table.sidebyside tr:nth-child (even) > td:nth-child(1) {
 background-color:  rgba(0,0,0,.05);
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <div style="width:600px; overflow: auto;">
   <table class="sidebyside table table-striped">
   <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>
      Bronze-High Deductible
    </th>
    <th>
      Silver-HMO
    </th>
    <th>
      Gold-PPO Low
    </th>
    <th>
      Gold-PPO Med
    </th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Score: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="text-green">
     95 </span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="text-yellow">
     77 </span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="text-danger">
     32 </span>
    </td>
    <td>
     <span class="text-danger">
     24 </span>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     RealCost: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $4,7772.32
    </td>
    <td>
      $6,024.81
    </td>
    <td>
      $8,194.55
    </td>
    <td>
      $8,194.55
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Premiums: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $2,400.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $3,100.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $3,956.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $3,956.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Cost of Services: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $1,575.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $2,239.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $2,983.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $2,983.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Cost of Medications: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $797.32
    </td>
    <td>
      $927.32
    </td>
    <td>
      $1,198.46
    </td>
    <td>
      $1,198.46
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    <td colspan="4">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Individual Deductible: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $3,350.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $3,850.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $4,250.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $4,250.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Individual Out of Pocket Maximum: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $6,350.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $6,850.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $7,050.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $7,050.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Family Deductible: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $6,650.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $6,950.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $7,200.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $7,200.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Family Out of Pocket Maximum: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $12,900.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $13,900.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $15,400.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $15,400.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Coinsurance: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      20%
    </td>
    <td>
      20%
    </td>
    <td>
      30%
    </td>
    <td>
      30%
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Copayment: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $25.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $30.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $40.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $40.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Pharmacy Generic: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $20.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $35.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $45.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $45.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Pharmacy Brand: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $40.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $45.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $60.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $60.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Pharmacy Non Preferred: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $60.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $70.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $80.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $80.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Mail Order Generic: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $60.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $80.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $90.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $90.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Mail Order Brand: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $80.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $90.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $100.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $100.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>
     Mail Order Non Preferred: </b>
    </td>
    <td>
      $120.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $140.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $175.00
    </td>
    <td>
      $175.00
    </td>
   </tr>
   </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, can you please include your current CSS and a snippet of the HTML so that we can see what your actual code environment is? You can probably apply a class to the single column you want hidden, but we need to see your code to answer for sure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TylerH - I've added my code to the original post.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow what you are wanting. You mean something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/1b329d8u/

Comment: I took what you did and modified it to this: https://jsfiddle.net/1b329d8u/2/

That's what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/1b329d8u/2/ is what I was trying to achieve.

```css
table.sidebyside {
    width: 800px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.sidebyside th:nth-child(1), .sidebyside td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 300px !important;
    position:absolute;
}
.sidebyside th:nth-child(2), .sidebyside td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-left: 300px !important;
}
.sidebyside th {
    background-color: #4b91ea;
    height: 63px;
} 
.sidebyside tr:nth-child(even)  > td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #fff;
}
.sidebyside tr:nth-child(odd) > td:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #f7fafa;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div style="width:600px; overflow: auto;">
            <table class="sidebyside table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Bronze-High Deductible</th>
                        <th>Silver-HMO</th>
                        <th>Gold-PPO Low</th>
                        <th>Gold-PPO Med</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Score: </b></td>
                        <td><span class="text-green">95 </span></td>
                        <td><span class="text-yellow">77 </span></td>
                        <td><span class="text-danger">32 </span></td>
                        <td><span class="text-danger">24 </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>RealCost: </b></td>
                        <td>$4,7772.32</td>
                        <td>$6,024.81</td>
                        <td>$8,194.55</td>
                        <td>$8,194.55</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Premiums: </b></td>
                        <td>$2,400.00</td>
                        <td>$3,100.00</td>
                        <td>$3,956.00</td>
                        <td>$3,956.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Cost of Services: </b></td>
                        <td>$1,575.00</td>
                        <td>$2,239.00</td>
                        <td>$2,983.00</td>
                        <td>$2,983.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Cost of Medications: </b></td>
                        <td>$797.32</td>
                        <td>$927.32</td>
                        <td>$1,198.46</td>
                        <td>$1,198.46</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="4"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Individual Deductible: </b></td>
                        <td>$3,350.00</td>
                        <td>$3,850.00</td>
                        <td>$4,250.00</td>
                        <td>$4,250.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Individual Out of Pocket Maximum: </b></td>
                        <td>$6,350.00</td>
                        <td>$6,850.00</td>
                        <td>$7,050.00</td>
                        <td>$7,050.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Family Deductible: </b></td>
                        <td>$6,650.00</td>
                        <td>$6,950.00</td>
                        <td>$7,200.00</td>
                        <td>$7,200.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Family Out of Pocket Maximum: </b></td>
                        <td>$12,900.00</td>
                        <td>$13,900.00</td>
                        <td>$15,400.00</td>
                        <td>$15,400.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Coinsurance: </b></td>
                        <td>20%</td>
                        <td>20%</td>
                        <td>30%</td>
                        <td>30%</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Copayment: </b></td>
                        <td>$25.00</td>
                        <td>$30.00</td>
                        <td>$40.00</td>
                        <td>$40.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Pharmacy Generic: </b></td>
                        <td>$20.00</td>
                        <td>$35.00</td>
                        <td>$45.00</td>
                        <td>$45.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Pharmacy Brand: </b></td>
                        <td>$40.00</td>
                        <td>$45.00</td>
                        <td>$60.00</td>
                        <td>$60.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Pharmacy Non Preferred: </b></td>
                        <td>$60.00</td>
                        <td>$70.00</td>
                        <td>$80.00</td>
                        <td>$80.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Mail Order Generic: </b></td>
                        <td>$60.00</td>
                        <td>$80.00</td>
                        <td>$90.00</td>
                        <td>$90.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Mail Order Brand: </b></td>
                        <td>$80.00</td>
                        <td>$90.00</td>
                        <td>$100.00</td>
                        <td>$100.00</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>Mail Order Non Preferred: </b></td>
                        <td>$120.00</td>
                        <td>$140.00</td>
                        <td>$175.00</td>
                        <td>$175.00</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks @TylerH for the solution. I had to use tr:nth-child(even)  > td:nth-child(1) so I could target the 1st column only and use (even) and (odd) at the tr level.

Answer (score 1):

For **even** use

```
table tr td:nth-child(even)
```

And for **odd** use

```
table tr td:nth-child(odd)
```

Moreover, always prefer to use the exact descendants you want to apply your css on to avoid any invalid html markup to be selected by your stylesheets.

Comment: bootstrap's "table-striped" does this already. It's in the code I just put into my updated post

Comment: You didn&#39;t mention that you are using bootstrap in your question. The question was about handling it with native css.

Comment: Sorry I didn't put that it was with Bootstrap at the time I made the post. I apologize.